# I'm facing Connection refused exception when trying to run this code

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

Producer Code

I am start of learning RabbitMQ tutorials. This is my very first time am trying to send message.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Send {
      private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";
      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
          ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
          factory.setHost("localhost");
          try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
               Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
              channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
              String message = "Hello World!";
              channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
              System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
          }
      }
    }
```

Consumer Code

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Recv {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

      }
}
```

I am facing this exception while trying to run both the producer and consumer

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1104)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1021)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1180)
    at producer.Send.main(Send.java:12)
```

I need to run this program without facing this connection refused exception

Comment: Is the RabbitMQ server running on `localhost` with the default port and the default user `guest`?

Comment: yes, it is running on localhost, but not sure about the default user - guest. But I haven't made any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the username, password and the virtual host in the ConnectionFactory in order to open a connection. RabbitMQ expects a value for the virtual host to which it tries to make a connection.

By default, RabbitMQ creates a `guest` user and a `/` virtual host and gives administrator role to the guest user over the created virtual host

User details:

1. Username: `guest`
2. Password: `guest`
3. VirtualHost: `/`

You can set these values in the `ConnectionFactory` as follows:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost")
factory.setUser("guest")
factory.setPassword("guest")
factory.setVirtualHost("/")
```